# Large dict RAM efficiency, re-assignment vs. update()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a large dict of dicts which effectively has the following format:

```
my_dict = { 
  'A' : { 
    'B' : { 
      'C' : {
        'key': 'value' 
}}}}
```

The nest of A, B, C may be up to 20 deep and the deepest level of key: value pairs can easily be 3000 entries long, so I expect this to use a reasonable amount of RAM as it is.

Initially when working with this, all the values at level C are actually a string called 'value' which is later updated by a for loop and replaced with a number determined elsewhere.

Currently I simply re-assign with something like

```
updated_value = 0.23453
my_dict['A']['B']['C']['key'] = updated_value
```

vs. something like

```
updated_value = 0.23453
my_dict['A']['B']['C'].update({key: updated_value})
```

As I mention above I expect this structure to use a reasonable amount of RAM but it seems to be using a lot more RAM than I'd really expect to see.

So 2 questions:
Is there a better data structure I could use for this other than a dict, given I need the hierarchy this describes?

By re-assigning with = vs. using update() (given how python passes info by reference) am I actually using up more RAM than I need to? (I'm wondering if, when using = here, the placeholder 'value' string is actually persisted in RAM even though I've re-assigned the key in the dict to a new number further down).

Thanks in advance for any thoughts :)

Comment: my first question would be, is it really necessary for you to use such deep nested dictionaries?

Comment: Dictionary is a data-type that is really fast at retrieving data, but it has a memory overhead. In Most cases a dictionary will have double the size of the element its holding. If you don't need all the elements, you can lazy-load parts of it.

Comment: @Shinratensei As I said in the post, I need the hierarchy, but if you have a better suggestion for a more appropriate data type then would be interested to hear about it.

Comment: I guess your data is more complicated than what you are showing here, but you could avoid all that deepness while maintaining the structure with a key like `'A-B-C'` so `my_dict['A-B-C']['key']`

Comment: That data structure doesnt seem right. You can probably transform it to a table with Pandas, or store it a single HDF5 file and access it without having it in memory all the time. As for your question: `.update(..)` only works if your last level is another dictionary, which would mean that you initialized it wrong in th first place.

Comment: Or use tuples as keys. (`my_dict[(a, b, c)]`)

Comment: @JoseA. In other parts of this work when I can get away with that that's actually what I do but in this particular case I need this hierarchy. 
My guess here though is that, this part of the hierarchy isn't really the problem RAM wise (as it's overall significantly fewer items that the deepest dict at level 'C') but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: @ImanolLuengo you're right - I've typo-ed the above when mentioning the use of update() there - will correct the original post

Comment: Using assignment on a key should not incur in extra memory usage, and most certainly the `'value'` string is not causing a big overhead (probably you have only one string and references to it). If anything `update` should be more expensive since it creates a new dict every time.

Comment: From what I've read, dictionaries use a very small amount of memory, so I'd say that the data structure is not the problem. It depends on the amount of entries though.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this hierarchy? What do you do with that dict later, that this hierarchy is needed? I can't think of a single purpose of such a hierarchy .You seem not to want to give us detailed information of your data, but a little hint could give us new ideas.